# Android Tabhost within Tabhost Not Working (XML issue I think)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tabhost

I have done this before, but for the life of me I cant remember.
I'm wanting a tab with in a tab. This is my mainactivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabHost.TabSpec Login = tabHost.newTabSpec("Login");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        Login.setIndicator("", getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1));
        Intent LoginIntent = new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class);
        LoginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Login.setContent(LoginIntent);


        // Tab for jobs
        TabHost.TabSpec Jobs = tabHost.newTabSpec("Jobs");
        Jobs.setIndicator("", getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2));
        Intent JobsIntent = new Intent(this, Tab2Activity.class);
        JobsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Jobs.setContent(JobsIntent);


        TabHost.TabSpec Jobs3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Jobs3");
        Jobs3.setIndicator("", getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab3));
        Intent JobsIntent3 = new Intent(this, Tab3Activity.class);
        JobsIntent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Jobs3.setContent(JobsIntent3);



        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(Login);
        tabHost.addTab(Jobs);
        tabHost.addTab(Jobs3);
    }
```

**This is Tab2Activity.java**

```
public class Tab2Activity extends TabActivity
{



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab2);

        /////////////////////////

        TabHost tabHost2 = getTabHost();

        TabHost.TabSpec Gmapped = tabHost2.newTabSpec("InnerTabs");

        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        Gmapped.setIndicator("", getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab3));
        Intent GmappedIntent = new Intent(this, Tab3Activity.class);
        GmappedIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Gmapped.setContent(GmappedIntent);

        tabHost2.addTab(Gmapped);
}
```

**and Tab2.xml**

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#332b2b"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:orientation="vertical" >



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/veganfestival"

                android:text="Aberdeen"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"

                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blank"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#6f844a" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Venue"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="City"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postcode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Postcode"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#6f844a" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Vdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Vtime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#6f844a" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blankagain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nav"

                android:text="Take Me There"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"

                />


        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have not been developing long, but I understand I need to at TabHost to Tab2.xml, but unsure were. Could someone help out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an advice, use `TabLayout` instead, is more easy:

[TabLayout Example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments)

Comment: Yer. Thanks. I did that but had issues with adding icons.

Comment: add icons in a tab?

Comment: Could you elaborate - as I may have said i'm fairly new to Android development.